# Launch Screen Showing Out of Proportion

Tags: ios, objective-c, launching-application, launchimage, launch-screen

I am using Xcode 6 and working with having my launch screen showing up on all different types of iDevices including iPad, iPhone 4, 5, 6. When it launches though it shows the writing and copy-write half off the screen for some reason and I was wondering how I can fix this so it shows universally on all my devices. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to make different images for each device or use a launch file xib using size classes to get all the device sizes included. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html).

Comment: I have but it does not explain exactly how to fix it or set it to certain coordinates

Comment: You have created a launch file or a set of images?

Comment: I was planning on using the default because I got a background color set and just my app name with the copyright underneath. All I really need is exactly coordinates in which it would be right in the middle to fit iPhone 4, 5, and 6. Please and thank you bud.

Comment: I would expect apple to reject an app that was using the default screen that shows up. But you could create what you are talking about with a launch file since it is a xib file that you build like normal and can use constraints to place a couple of labels, though apples docs say the launch file is supposed to show your interface, the link I posted has some good examples of what they really want.

Comment: I would use photoshop or gimp to create the wording you want and save it as an image. In Xcode, Add a new file, choose Launch Screen from the User Interface section. Add a UIImageView, assign your image to it, use autolayout to align the UIImageView horizontally and vertically. This would be the easiest way to accomplish this. Otherwise you will need to add a couple of UILabels and line them up with autolayout.